# SUM same column user score

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

How to make two sum process on same column? I tried:

```
SELECT SUM(score)
FROM user
WHERE id = 33
or id = 44
group by id
```

I need to get score of (user 33) and (user 44) separately.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add the result you get? This SQL looks ok for me?

Comment: select id, sum(score)...

Comment: Simple rule: all columns listed in GROUP BY must always be inside SELECT (plus aggregation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group by id, and then filter using `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT id, SUM(score)
FROM user
group by id
having id = 33 or id = 44
```

[As @Jens pointed out, your original query works just fine: [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd91a3/4) ]

Comment: yeah, accepted, but clearly this isn't really getting to the heart of the problem. The crucial point is the inclusion of id in your select